# Is SRAM road 11-speed 11-42 cassette compatible with Shimano MTB 11 speed?

Tags: shimano, sram

I know that SRAM has adopted Shimano specs for chains and cassettes so they should be interchangeable but before I buy, I'd like to confirm. Are these cassettes interchangeable:

1. SRAM PG-1130 11-42 - **marketed for NX (MTB) 1x11 and Apex (road)
   1x11**
2. Shimano SLX CS-M7000 11-42 11-speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Same number of speeds, same range, same Hyperglide II freehub body compatibility.